# Gitian error while compiling Bitcoin dependencies for OSX

Tags: macos, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox, bitcoin, lxc

I'm trying to compile Bitcoin in Gitian for OSX. I've ran the following line.

```
./bin/gbuild ../bitcoin/contrib/gitian-descriptors/gitian-osx-native.yml
```

That produces an error in the build log as follows.

```
cd libprunetrie && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/build/osx-cross-depends/build/toolchain4-10cc648683617cca8bcbeae507888099b41b530c/cctools2odcctools/odcctools-809/libprunetrie'
mkdir -p `dirname PruneTrie.o`
In file included from allocate.c:29:0:
../include/stuff/errors.h:39:1: error: unknown type name ‘uint32_t’
../include/stuff/errors.h:79:5: error: unknown type name ‘kern_return_t’
../include/stuff/errors.h:86:5: error: unknown type name ‘kern_return_t’
```

What do I need to do to make this work? If I'm not including enough information, please let me know what you need me to tell you. I didn't change the yml file from the official Bitcoin sources or anything else and I'm compiling on a Ubuntu 12.04.4 64Bit VirtualBox instance using LXC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes accross this issue, it has something to do with the way a Mac OSX system packages the tar file. You can't package it on a regular Linux system, it has to be Darwin Unix. (Mac) I came accross the link below which points to a ready made version of the stripped down Apple SDK file for Bitcoin. (MacOSX10.7.sdk.tar.gz)

https://github.com/deuscoin/deuscoin/blob/master/doc/building-deuscoin.md

Hopefully this helps someone else.